# Certificado ssl para servidor

Tags: ssl, certificado-ssl

estoy intentando instalar un certificado para mi servidor backend el cual no tendra ningun dominio, al ejecutar el asistente de bitnami que lo genera automaticamente me pide nombre de dominio, yo coloco la direccion ip y me indica que no es valida

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Domains

Please provide a valid space-separated list of domains for which you wish to 
configure your web server.

Domain list [0.000.00.00]: 0.000.00.00

Warning: Please enter valid domains
Press [Enter] to continue:0.000.00.00
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Domains

Please provide a valid space-separated list of domains for which you wish to 
configure your web server.

Domain list [0.000.00.00]:
```

Coloco 0.000.00.00 para no exponer la direccion de mi servidor publicamente.

Que puedo hacer para generar el certificado ya que el dominio lo tengo solo para el front

Comment: Te piden A, tu pones B y te da error. Quizá debas de poner lo que pide.

Comment: Creo que no se puede instalar un certificado válido en un host sin dominio, [ver info](https://letsencrypt.org/es/docs/certificates-for-localhost/). Lo que puedes hacer es instalar un [certificado autofirmado](https://www.google.com/search?q=https+certificado+autofirmado), igual de seguro, para comunicar los endpoints dentro de localhost. Otra alternativa es usar [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert)